# is it a way to pend a signal of same type in c language?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, signal-processing

i really to need to make a signal pending when an another signal of same type is in handler.

Suppose SIGUSR2 is in handler and SIGUSR1 is a member of sa_mask.
if now the process receive SIGUSR1, it will be block and will be delivered after SIGUSR2 exited from handler which is reasonable.

But if process receive SIGUSR2 when it is processing another SIGUSR2 in handler, the second signal will be ignored for ever.

i want the SIGUSR2 be pended and delivered later. how can i do that?

Note: the below codes are just two example, if you understood my question there is no need to read them

the first scenario: child send two signal(SIGUSR1 & SIGUSR2) to parent. while SIGUSR1 is in handler the SIGUSR2 will be pending and delivered later:

```
    #define MAXCHILD 1
    void handler1(int signo)
      {
        switch(signo)
        {
          /* handling SIGUSR1 takes one second
          during this time if SIGUSR2 will be blocked on delivery. */
          case SIGUSR1:
          write(1,"SIGUSR1 received \n",strlen("SIGUSR1 received \n"));
          sleep(5);
          break;
          case SIGUSR2:
          write(1,"SIGUSR2 received \n",strlen("SIGUSR2 received \n"));
          break;
        }
      }
    int main()
    {
      struct sigaction action1;
      sigset_t set1;
      sigemptyset(&set1);
      sigaddset(&set1, SIGUSR2);//adding SIGUSR2 to set1
      sigaddset(&set1,SIGUSR1);
      action1.sa_handler = handler1;
      action1.sa_mask = set1;
      action1.sa_flags = 0;
      int inchild=0;
      sigaction(SIGUSR1,(struct sigaction *) &action1,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGUSR2,(struct sigaction *) &action1,NULL);
      pid_t parent=getpid();
      pid_t pid[MAXCHILD];
      for ( int i=0;i<MAXCHILD;i++)
      {
        pid[i]=fork();
        if( pid[i]==0)
        {
          inchild=1;
          break;
        }
      }
      while(inchild==0);
      if(inchild==1)
      {
        //child sends SIGUSR1 and immediately SIGUSR2 to parent
        kill(parent,SIGUSR1);
        kill(parent,SIGUSR2);
        sleep(1);
      }
      printf("end\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

the output of above code is:

```
SIGUSR1 received 
end
SIGUSR2 received
```

which is ok.

but let's talk about the second scenario: child send two signal(SIGUSR1) to parent. while SIGUSR1 is in handler the second SIGUSR1 will not be pending and will be ignored for ever:

```
    #define MAXCHILD 1
    void handler1(int signo)
      {
        switch(signo)
        {
          /* handling SIGUSR1 takes one second
          during this time if SIGUSR2 will be blocked on delivery. */
          case SIGUSR1:
          write(1,"SIGUSR1 received \n",strlen("SIGUSR1 received \n"));
          sleep(5);
          break;
          case SIGUSR2:
          write(1,"SIGUSR2 received \n",strlen("SIGUSR2 received \n"));
          break;
        }
      }
    int main()
    {
      struct sigaction action1;
      sigset_t set1;
      sigemptyset(&set1);
      sigaddset(&set1, SIGUSR2);//adding SIGUSR2 to set1
      sigaddset(&set1,SIGUSR1);
      action1.sa_handler = handler1;
      action1.sa_mask = set1;
      action1.sa_flags = 0;
      int inchild=0;
      sigaction(SIGUSR1,(struct sigaction *) &action1,NULL);
      sigaction(SIGUSR2,(struct sigaction *) &action1,NULL);
      pid_t parent=getpid();
      pid_t pid[MAXCHILD];
      for ( int i=0;i<MAXCHILD;i++)
      {
        pid[i]=fork();
        if( pid[i]==0)
        {
          inchild=1;
          break;
        }
      }
      while(inchild==0);
      if(inchild==1)
      {
        //child sends SIGUSR1 and immediately SIGUSR1 to parent
        kill(parent,SIGUSR1);
        kill(parent,SIGUSR1);
        sleep(1);
      }
      printf("end\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

i expect the output be:

```
SIGUSR1 received
end
SIGUSR1 received
```

but the output is:

```
SIGUSR1 received
end
```

which shows the second signal has been ignored for ever.

how can i reach my expected result when sending two signal of same type? i just want to be able get the second signal as a pending signal, is there a way to do that?

according to [this link](https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Signals,-Part-2:-Pending-Signals-and-Signal-Masks) there is no way to do that but i hope someone offer a fake way to do that or at least simulate that(but i want write() functions remain in handler).

Comment: It sounds like you want POSIX real-time signals, which are queued instead of being dropped.